# http server-side node.js data

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, http

I have html page using jQuery.

I want to send requests to node server but I don't know how to response to different requests, in other words how to distinguish between get\post request and how read the request body (undreastend what the user wanted) and response according to it.

```
var http = require("http");

function serve(request, response)
{
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
}

http.createServer(serve).listen(3001);
```

and in the client side, same question - how to send data?

```
Window.onload = function () {

    Document.getElementById('GoButton').click = function() {
        var xhr = new XHRObject();
        xhr.open("get","http://127.0.0.1:1337",true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange= function()
        {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        };
        request.send(null);

    };

};
```

and last thing : all this request&response should use json .

Comment: I think, you should consider using some web framework, e.g. [exptess](http://expressjs.com/), [koa](http://koajs.com/), [etc](http://codecondo.com/7-minimal-node-js-web-frameworks/).

Comment: and how that will help?

Answer (score 1):

To decide what you need to put in your response message, you need to check your `request` property. Taking a quick look at the api documentation, you can see that `request` is an instance of [IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_http_incomingmessage), and that it has a property called `method`.

If you want to reply something specific for all `POST` requests, you should check if `request.method === 'POST'`.

Either way, you're apparantly completely new to node, in which case you should probably read up a bit more. http://nodebeginner.org is a good resource to start with.

Comment: Well, that all depends on what exactly you're trying to send.
Generally speaking, suppose you have a javascript Object `var foo`, you would want to do something along these lines: `request.send(JSON.stringify(foo));`